# how to form a path to XML subnodes with a multidimensional array

Tags: php, xml, multidimensional-array

Where do I begin... a XML file needs to go into a database. Therefore I want to make a config array containing the mapping between XML nodes and table-columns of one table.

```
$maps = array(
 // 'node-name'=>'column-name'
 'prod_id'=>'supplier_product_id',
 'description'=>'product_description',
);

$xml=simplexml_load_file($file);

//just a test
foreach ($maps as $node => $col){
 echo 'node ' . $xml->$node . ' is mapped to: ' . $col; //this works
}
```

There is information I need to put in this (same) table, from a subnode. So I was thinking of putting subnodes in a nested array like this:

```
$maps = array(
 // 'node-name'=>'column-name'
 'prod_id'=>'supplier_product_id',
 'description'=>'product_description',
 // to access $xml->node->subnode;
 'category'=>array(
  'id'=>'category_id',
 ),
);
```

But now I get confused, how can I use the nested array to make an path to the node like this: 
`$xml->category->id`

I am a newbee in PHP and hopefully some help will keep me on the road again. 
All help is welcome, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$maps = array(
 // 'node-name'=>'column-name'
 'prod_id'=>'supplier_product_id',
 'description'=>'product_description',
 // to access $xml->node->subnode;
 'category'=>array(
  'id'=>'category_id'
 )
);

function getDataMapping( $maps, $child="" ) {
    global $file;

    $xml=simplexml_load_file($file);

    foreach ($maps as $node => $col) {
        if( is_array( $col ) ) {
            getDataMapping( $col, $node );
        } else {
            if( $child ) {
                echo 'node ' . $xml->{$child}->$node . ' is mapped to: ' . $col; //this works
            } else {
                echo 'node ' . $xml->$node . ' is mapped to: ' . $col; //this works
            }
        }
    }
}

getDataMapping( $maps );
?>
```

Obviously, if your nesting runs many levels deep (array within array and so on), you can change it to a recursive function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Pushpesh! 
The recursive function is what I'm interrested in, but I don't see how to do that yet... My problem is how to build up a sentence with the right syntax to access the sub-sub-sub-subnode's value. 
All node-names along the way up to the subnode can be stored in an array. But how to write it back with the 'arrows' ('->') to form the right syntax again? Like this: `$xml->{$node}->{subnode}->{subsubnode}->{subsubsubnode}`

Comment: have you seen my whole question, because I hit Enter too early and you did answer already? I think the syntax is not correct yet. If there are sub-sub-sub-childs the string must also stretch that number of subchilds, to get:
`$xml->{child}->{subchild}->{subsubchild}`
Or do I need another approach perhaps?

Comment: Well, what i have given you above is the template which works. `If you would care to show me the XML file, that you are working with, it would help me a long way in giving you a permament solution`. Otherwise, it's akin to shooting in the dark!!

Comment: I just realize there is actually no need to read more than 2 levels. So your answer is enough, because it can access both `$xml->node` and `$xml->child->node` . With xpath('//job') I can set a base node entrance to all the <job> nodes and iterate over them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<message>
<errorcode>100</errorcode>
<body>
 <jobs>
  <job>
   <id>1</id>
   <description>Nice job at the office</description>
   <hours>40</hours>
   <contact>
    <id>SYL</id>
    <name>Sylvia</name>
    <email>sylvia@mail.com</email>
   </contact>
  </job>
  <job>
   <id>2</id>
   <description>Construction work</description>
   <hours>32</hours>
   <contact>
    <id>HEN</id>
    <name>Hendrik</name>
    <email>hendrik@mail.com</email>
   </contact>
  </job>
 </jobs>
</body>
<attachements>
</attachements>
<filenames>
</filenames>
</message>
```

I just realize there is actually no need to read more than 2 levels. So your answer is enough, because it can access both $xml->node and $xml->child->node . With xpath('//job') I can set a base node entrance to all the  nodes and iterate over them.